# How can I get people to continue to respond to my question?

Tags: discussion

I currently have a question posted [I have partially uninstalled wireless driver iwl4965, wireless never worked, no option to install proprietary drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/694972/i-have-partially-uninstalled-wireless-driver-iwl4965-wireless-never-worked-no). And I haven't had a response in 2 weeks. What can I do to encourage the two experts who initially offered suggestions, to revisit my problem?  Or even encourage someone new to help?

I have a theory why this may be; one of the experts offered a significant series of suggestions ending with a request to report back on my findings, the second expert suggested that my question may have been answered by another post (which didn't even apply to my version of Ubuntu) and it has a +1 rating.

I reported back my findings, and no-one has left a single comment or suggestion since.  What happened?

Where did I go wrong?  Can I contact the folks who commented on my post directly? Can I mark my post as "still unanswered please help"?.

I'm new to Ubuntu/Linux.  I would really like to go a little deeper, but I can't even get anyone to respond to my post. Please help.

Comment: Tip: every time you edit the question to add more information, it jumps to the front of the home page.

Comment: But don't repeatedly bump too often, ppl get annoyed that way :) BTW its in the process being of marked a dupe of [this question](https://askubuntu.com//questions/93447/how-do-i-get-my-lenovo-t61-to-connect-to-a-wireless-networ), if that doesn't help SAY SO. BTW the @NAME things probably only work in comments

Answer (score 22):

People answer questions when they think they have a possible solution. Almost all of the experienced users here refrain from answering or even commenting when they feel that they have little or nothing to contribute that's useful.

Your case is an excellent example of what I call my least favorite problem; everything looks perfect, except it just doesn't work. When I and, I suspect, several of my colleagues look at your question, we are unable to come up with suggestions beyond what has been suggested and then implemented by you.

However, having said this, and spurred by a bounty (!!), I will make a further attempt.

Answer (score 1):

Just start a **bounty** and make answering the question more attractive to those that know. Sometimes there is just noone that has a solution. In that case you should think about a **bug report** to help devellopers fix yet unknown or not-yet-investigated issues (though bug reports are off topic here as questions, and not everything needs a bug report)

Comment: Bug reports only apply to issues in the software itself and most issues we see on Ask Ubuntu don't need bug reports...

Comment: If so, why will they not be answered?

Comment: Bug reports are off topic here.  If you aren't getting answers then post a bounty to stimulate answering.  although if nobody knows that's a problem, likely one of the issues being seein in your case here.